# Why a folder needs a execute permission when I'm trying to execute a .sh?

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, scripts, chmod

I've got a folder that has 0600 chmod permission and this folder has a sh script. 
I'm trying to limit some permissions but I've realized that if the folder has not a execute permission, unless for the user, I can't access using cd command, so that I can't execute my script.
The script has the proper permission (0700)

Is this right? I don't understand why. Could anybody explain me the function of execute permission in folders?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's basically how it works - a directory has to have execution bit set to allow user/group member/others to enter it.

More interestingly - you don't really need read permissions on the directory to access file inside it - as long, as you know the file name, since you can't list contents of directories if you have no read permissions.

I think the key to understand it is to realize that in Linux/Unix there really is no such thing like directory. It's also a file - containing information about the other files - its contents.

Anyway - some reading about those basics will be a good idea, I'd say.
This may be a good start: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions

Comment: Sin problema amigo.